# cannot find uninstalled Android application at Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I've installed and uninstalled the freedompop messaging application a few times.  The last time I installed it, it worked fine.  But I needed to start the application from fresh so I uninstalled it.  I also clicked "x" to remove it from uninstalled application list (It happened before and that time I did not remove it from the uninstalled list.  So when I could not find this application, I removed it from the uninstalled application list.  Then I could find this application to install).  But this time, after removing it from the uninstalled application list, I still could not find this application.  The only one available is "freedompop messaging tips".   But that was not the one I needed.

I also used browser to access Google Play Store directly and this application was not on MY ADROID APPS list.  So Google Play Store was synched with my device.  I even did "FORCED STOP", "CLEAR DATA" and "CLEAR CACHE" for Google Play Store before searching for this application.  But I still could not find it.

This application is offered by my mobile carrier so it would not be removed from Google Play Store.  Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Play Store and I can't see the app either. It must have been hidden or removed. Don't worry, though. You can get the .APK file [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/freedompop/freedompop-messaging/freedompop-messaging-19-01-692-1208-release/freedompop-messaging-19-01-692-1208-android-apk-download/).

Answer (score 0):

Trying installing it from the playstore website:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freedompop.phone&hl=en_GB

If it does not show then it might be that it is incompatible with your phone which would mean you would need to find the APK elsewhere.